# No search handler with name: solr_query found for Solr query

Tags: solr, cassandra, cql, datastax-enterprise, cql3

I am trying to run a Solr query in CQL. I have configured the solrconfig.xml file with the new handler

```
<requestHandler class="com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.component.CqlSearchHandler" name="solr_query" />
```

Also after doing this process, I curl my file to

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/resource/nhanes_ks.nhanes/solrconfig.xml --data-binary @solrconfig.xml -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

But when I run the query

```
select * from nhanes_ks.nhanes where solr_query = 'dog:yes';
```

I get the error as

```
Bad Request: No search handler with name: solr_query found for Solr query:
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you starting with the solrconfig.xml that comes with DSE? If so, why are you modifying it? Stick with the DSE solrconfig.xml until you have the example fully working.

Comment: The solrconfig.xml that came with DSE did not have the solr_query search handler. I followed phact's answer and applied `generateResources=true` after which the search handler got registered and started working. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running DSE 4.6, you no longer have to create or post your own solr_config.xml (or schema.xml for that matter). DSE will generate them for you. Follow one of these two procedures:

Http method:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=<keyspace>.<table>&generateResources=true"
```

dsetool method:

```
dsetool create_core <keyspace>.<table> generateResources=true
```

Details in the [DataStax Docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCreateCoreAuto.html)